# is the set of algebraic numbers equivalent to rays of R-dense projections?

Tags: set-theory

ok, the title is made of words I made up for lack of vocabulary. so let's define the words I used in the title:

$\mathbb{R}$-dense is a set dense in $\mathbb{R}$, rays of such a set means I take countably many points on the circle and draw a line from zero through these points right into infinity, and then replace that continuous line by another countable set of points. the question if this will ever give me all algebraic numbers with the right choice of countable sets for the circle and the rays is quite surely positive, just choose those sets as polar coordinates of the algebraic numbers. but I had a particular representation in mind:

$U_j:=\{\Re e^{\pi i u}:u\in U_{j-1}\}\cup U_{j-1}$ where $\Re$ gives the real part of a complex number. $U_0:=\mathbb{Q}$

$D(X):=\{xe^{\pi i y},x^{-1}e^{\pi i y}:x,y\in X\}$

$\mathbb{D}:=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} D(U_j)$

question: is $\mathbb{D}$ equivalent to algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$? if not, show me a number not in this set or in this set but not an algebraic number. if yes, show me a function mapping algebraic numbers (represented by characteristic polynomial) to $(j,x,y)$ where $y\in U_j$ and $x\in U_j\cup U_j^{-1}$ certifying that this algebraic number is in $U_j$.

Comment: I think numbers like $\cos(\sqrt2)$ come into your $U_j$, and I think such numbers are known not to be algebraic.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help, $\sqrt{2}\over\pi$ isn't in any $U_j$! can you show $\cos(\pi\cdot\sqrt{2})$ is transcendental?